# Incorrect message on tooltip on flagged comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, comment-flags

I flagged a comment as obsolete. The flag hasn't been handled yet. When hovering on the flag icon, I'm told that I “flagged this comment as unconstructive, offensive, or spam”.

[image: screenshot]

No, I didn't flag this comment as being intrinsically bad. I flagged it as no longer relevant. I know that the text of comment flags doesn't make a difference to the software, but it does to humans. The tooltip shouldn't lie. I don't mind if it summarizes all the recognized flag reasons, but if it does so, it shouldn't discount common flag reasons.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a problem on SO; I have the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. I have changed the tooltip to be more generic. It now says:

> You have already flagged this comment

This will be live in the next production build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.26.2606`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.26.1893`).